# Where to use the makeCurrent() in QGLWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

The qt's documentation said:

> Your widget's OpenGL rendering context is made current when paintGL(),
>   resizeGL(), or initializeGL() is called. If you need to call the
>   standard OpenGL API functions from other places (e.g. in your widget's
>   constructor or in your own paint functions), you must call
>   makeCurrent() first.

for the following case:

```
paintGL()
{
    drawSomething();
}
...
drawSomething()
{
    glClearColor()...
    //many other gl calls...
}
```

do I have to makeCurrent inside the `drawSomething()` function.

And if I only make QPainter call in stead of standard OpenGL API functions. Do I have to use makeCurrent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> do I have to makeCurrent inside the drawSomething() function.

If that function is called only from `paintGL`, no, as Qt will call `paintGL` with the context already current.

As the docs say, you'll need it whenever you need the GL context current in some other function.

```
// called from other code, context may not be current
void MyGLWidget::setBackgroundColor(const QColor &color) {
     makeCurrent();
     glClearColor(color.redF(), color.greenF(), color.blueF(), color.alphaF());
}
```

Comment: So how about qpainter? If I onlu use qpainter in a qglwidget, is it necessary to call makecurrent?

Comment: Inside `paintEvent`? No, it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation states:

> [The] rendering context is made current when paintGL() ... is called

So there is no need to call `makeCurrent` in any method called from paintGL. When using QPainter, it is also not necessary (Btw.: QPainter does not necessarily use OpenGL).

Comment: But according to my test, the QPainter uses OPenGL in GLWidget?

Comment: @Nyaruko: yes, it does.